# How to get an xml value depending on node attribute in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, attributes

Let's say we have the following xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<OrderExchangeMessage version="9.0" type="AddOrder"
    xmlns:xs="xxx"
    xmlns:xsi="xxx"
    xmlns="xxx">
    <Command>
        <AddOrderRequest>
            <Order>
                <OrderID>xxx</OrderID>
                <InnerOrder>
                    <RestorationOrder version="5.0">
                        <ModelElements>
                            <ModelElement displayName="red car">
                                <files>
                                    <file path="pathtofile"/>
                                </files>
                            </ModelElement>
                            <ModelElement displayName="red truck">
                                <files>
                                    <file path="pathtofile"/>
                                </files>
                            </ModelElement>
                            <ModelElement displayName="green car">
                                <files>
                                    <file path="pathtofile"/>
                                </files>
                            </ModelElement>
                        </ModelElements>
                    </RestorationOrder>
                </InnerOrder>
            </Order>
        </AddOrderRequest>
    </Command>
</OrderExchangeMessage>
```

How can I retrieve the value of file path only if the attribute of ModelElement contains "red" ?

> So I need to know which file goes for a red car and which file for a red truck.

I also tried to get a parent in order to look for child, but got no luck so far.

```
XmlNodeList? nodeListItems = xmldoc.SelectNodes("/OrderExchangeMessage[@version='9.0']/" +
                                                                    "Command/AddOrderRequest/Order/InnerOrder/" +
                                                                    "RestorationOrder[@version='5.0']/" +
                                                                    "ModelElements");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(xml);
    
    XmlNodeList modelElements = doc.GetElementsByTagName("ModelElement");
    foreach (XmlNode modelElement in modelElements)
    {
        XmlNode displayName = modelElement.Attributes.GetNamedItem("displayName");
        if (displayName != null && displayName.Value.Contains("red"))
        {
            XmlNode path = modelElement["files"]["file"].Attributes.GetNamedItem("path");
            Console.WriteLine(path.Value);
        }
    }
```

This should do the trick.

> xml is the xml document

This code iterates all ModelElement and Checks displayName for the value of red

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your `SelectNodes` code, you'll have to have a `NameSpaceManager`, and the xpath has to have "xxx:" before each node path.

```
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmldoc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("xxx", xmldoc.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI);
XmlNodeList? nodeListItems = xmldoc.SelectNodes("/xxx:OrderExchangeMessage[@version='9.0']/xxx:" +
                                                                "Command/xxx:AddOrderRequest/xxx:Order/xxx:InnerOrder/xxx:" +
                                                                "RestorationOrder[@version='5.0']/xxx:" +
                                                                "ModelElements", nsmgr);
```

Comment: Didn't know I had to use "xxx:" before each node path, very userfull.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution.

It is using LINQ to XML API of the .Net Framework. It is available since 2007.

The input XML has a default namespace. It should be taken care of.

**c#**

```
void Main()
{
    const string filePath = @"e:\Temp\LockedInside.xml";
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(filePath);
    
    XNamespace ns = xdoc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();

    var ModelElements = xdoc.Descendants(ns + "ModelElement")?
      .Where(d => d.Attributes("displayName").FirstOrDefault().Value.StartsWith("red"));
    
    foreach (var ModelElement in ModelElements)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("displayName='{0}', file_path='{1}'"
            , ModelElement.Attribute("displayName").Value
            , ModelElement.Element(ns + "files").Element(ns + "file").Attribute("path").Value);
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
displayName='red car', file_path='pathtofile'
displayName='red truck', file_path='pathtofile'
```

Comment: Instead of `Value.StartsWith("red")` I would use `Value.Split(' ').Contains("red")`, since red could be in other positions, or you could have other word that starts with red, like redmond, as the attribute value.

Comment: @Magnetron, I guess it depends on the actual real  life data. I was following a small sample that was provided by the OP.